# Prove that $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 1 - x$ when $x$ is irrational is continuous at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Prove that the function :  $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 1 - x$ when $x$ is irrational is continuous at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

To prove the continuity
it is necessary to prove that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(\frac{1}{2})| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x -c| < \delta$ $- (1).$

Now if we choose $a \in (\frac{1}{2} - \delta, \frac{1}{2} + \delta)$ and also $a$ is rational and choose $\epsilon < |a - \frac{1}{2}|$ then condition in $(1)$ is not satisfied.  How to move from here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Please show your work. Show where you are stuck. This will show you are genuinely interested in math. Otherwise, the question will be closed and is less likely to get good answers.

Comment: A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can show this by using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, by first noticing that $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and then looking at $x \in \mathbb{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $x \in \mathbb{\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}}$ seperately.